# Disable quote wrapping in block edit mode

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I have recently used brackets editor and was blown away with it's multiple cursor support.

As good as Brackets is, it doesn't meet my needs for PHP and I make use of Aptana which is basically Eclipse IDE.

I am very frustrated with block edit mode wrapping the contents when I enter a single / double quote and I am hoping somebody out there can come to the rescue.

[image: eclipse block edit mode quote issues]

As you can see above I have selected a couple of lines and as soon as I have typed the quote (doesn't matter if it's a single or double) it has wrapped the entire content in my block selection rather than inserted a quote, there is also a secondary issue in that once the quotes are in there, the cursor is actually before the opening quote but that's another issue entirely!

I have gone through my preferences based on other answers I have found and have disabled "automatic literal closing" in my typing settings but this hasn't had the desired effect.

So my question is, How do I get block edit mode to not wrap the contents in quotes but insert a quote mark instead?

On a side note I think that this is actually how the block select mode is intended to work and I am just being hopeful.

Additional Notes:

I've edited my bundles for HTML / TEXT / PHP to remove the auto insertion of double and single quotes and still no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without creating a plugin to automatically trigger it for you, the only other option is to click Window then Preferences. In the Preferences box, navigate to Aptana Studio then Editors, and uncheck "Auto-close matching character pairs" while you do your block quote edit, then re-enable it if necessary.

You would also have to disable HTML from automatically closing tags, which can be found in the HTML tab of the Editors settings.

Without looking to create a plugin to do this legwork for you, this is the only way around it.